# Ways to translate/say, "as much as"/"to the same extent as"

Tags: перевод

I am aware that one way to express 'as much [X] as' between one quantity and another is by 'столько, сколько..."

For example: "В течение недели пес сожрал столько же, сколько в полтора последних голодных месяца на улице." (In the course of a week, the dog devoured as much [food] as in his last, hungry month-and-a-half on the street.)

What are some other ways to express this comparison?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps in some cases you can use "так же, как и", for instance:

> I was **as much** scared **as** intrigued.
>   Я был **так же** напуган, **как и** заинтригован. =  Я был **настолько же** напуган, **насколько** заинтригован.

In some contexts, the construct "**и ..., и ... в равной мере**" could be used (with variations like "**в равной мере и ..., и ...**")

That depends on the context, of course.

Comment: Also "столь же".